Counting values in a Long data type range
I am learning scala and thought this would be easy and straight forward, however each try results in a More than Int.MaxValue elements. error. I am trying to count all odd occurences in a range using Long type.
It seems as though; count, size and length all deal with type Int. So which methods can I use to get the correct values?:
def oddCount(n: Long): Long = {
  (1L to n by 2L).size // Though this would reduce the size of the range
  // Range.Long(1L, n, 1L).count(_ % 2 != 0) Another way I tried
}

>>> More than Int.MaxValue elements.


For example:
input n=7 should output 3 since there are 3 odd numbers from 1 to 7 => [1, 3, 5]

Can't find it but pretty sure this has already been discussed here. Ranges have this limitation because they are backed by an Array if I remember correctly and an Array (in the JVM) cannot contain that many elements. Depending on what you'd want to do in a real situation, there'd be other solutions.

Range isn't Array-backed. The individual elements aren't stored at all, only the bounds and step size. Any size Range fits in a constant, small amount of memory.

Using any collection for counting odd numbers in range is just wrong tool. You simply need return n/2. I understand this is just an example but... find better one. Maybe real problem from leetcode or adventOfCode

@Scalway, Yeah, you are right. I had completed that example by using n/2 but left the question open as I was waiting to see if someone would respond by answering what you can use for collections of Long type.

Since NumericRange doesn't support more than Int.MaxValue elements (which makes sense for strict collections) you may do something like this:
def oddCount(n: Long): Long =
  LazyList.iterate(start = 1L)(_ + 1L).takeWhile(_ <= n).foldLeft(0L) {
    case (acc, x) =>
      if ((x % 2) != 0) acc + 1L else acc
  }

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Bwfc2QLTQgCRBVYFKnSgHg/9

It takes a while for numbers bigger than Int.MaxValue and thus they timeout on Scastie.

Note: Despite what the comment says, this does not hold all the data in memory. The foldLeft will materialize and fold one element at a time, meaning this is equivalent to a while loop (probably slower due to boxing and indirections though).
Whether or not this is the best way to solve the meta-problem is another discussion.

Edit
This solution is wrong for now since it is actually delegating to NumericRange as well.
def oddCount(n: Long): Long =
  LazyList.range(start = 1L, end = n).foldLeft(0L) { case (acc, x) =>
    if ((x % 2) != 0) acc + 1L else acc
  }

But, it will be eventually fixed: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/10767

You may also use Iterator.range instead of LazyList.range.

No cigar :). That fails at runtime(!) with More than Int.MaxValue elements. if end is more than (1<<32 - 1). Also, I would advice against using lazy lists for this (or  for pretty mush anything frankly), because accumulating tens of billions of entries in memory as you traverse it just seems silly even if it manages to not crash the whole app.
